# Proper usage of 'if so'

Tags: grammar

I want to know if this sentence is grammatically correct.

*Is there anyone else who have access to admin panel? If so, please provide us all ip addresses from all users in order to monitor your website traffic.*

Comment: Why do you think there might be a problem?

Comment: I see the same question on ELL.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP has also asked it on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33778/proper-usage-of-if-so). It's also General Reference, and ***proofreading***.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few grammatical errors in the sentence but the use of "If so" is not one of them. This is how you would correct those errors;

> Is there anyone else who *has* access to *the* admin panel? If so, *could they* please provide us *with the* IP addresses *of all of the* users, in order to monitor your website traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest

> Could you please find someone with access to the admin panel, who can provide us with the IP addresses of all of the users in order for us to monitor your website traffic?